# How to use grep output in EOF?

Tags: grep, eof, tcsh

I am a new leaner and I am running a program with following script:

```
./Multiwfn >HF-Dr.out << EOF
HF.fchk
3
21
2
2
grep 'Global surface minimum:' HF-ESP.out | awk '{print $7,$8,$9,$7,$8,$9}'
EXIT
EOF
```

The output of this grep is something like:

`0.043532  -0.032964   1.960094  0.043532  -0.032964   1.960094`

I want to use the output of grep instead of input in the script, i.e. I want the script like:

```
./Multiwfn >HF-Dr.out << EOF
HF.fchk
3
21
2
2
0.043532  -0.032964   1.960094  0.043532  -0.032964   1.960094
EXIT
EOF
```

Is there any way that I hide (make non-executable) the grep input from my program and use only its output? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just use command substitution: `$(grep ... )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the 'make non-executable' part of your question. As I understand it, you want it executed before it is given to `./Multiwfn`.

There are several solutions:

1) PesaThe's comment:

```
./Multiwfn >HF-Dr.out << EOF
HF.fchk
3
21
2
2
$(grep 'Global surface minimum:' HF-ESP.out | awk '{print $7,$8,$9,$7,$8,$9}')
EXIT
EOF
```

2) Create the input in a pipe:

```
(echo -e "HF.fchk\n3\n21\n2\n2;grep 'Global surface minimum:' HF-ESP.out | awk '{print $7,$8,$9,$7,$8,$9}';echo EXIT) | ./Multiwfn >HF-Dr.out
```

3) use an intermediate file:

```
cat > file <<EOF
HF.fchk
3
21
2
2
EOF
grep 'Global surface minimum:' HF-ESP.out | awk '{print $7,$8,$9,$7,$8,$9}' >> file
echo EXIT >> file
./Multiwfn < file >HF-Dr.out
rm file
```

I'm sure that there are more ways, but this should put you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am running this program in tcsh. When I used the first solution suggested by you , I got error "  Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters."
I modified it by replacing "$" with" ` ". But This time I got following series of errors:
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,,,,,}
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
 and so on.

Comment: My tcsh is not as good as my bash. If I were you, I'd go for the last solution (I tested that on tcsh and it works).  Could you please alter the tag `bash` to `tcsh`, because you're not using bash?

Comment: I worked for me. Thank you very much dear. So nice of you. Thank you for your time and help.